# imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); does not work with a valid, correctly scaled Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am trying to display a Bitmap in an ImageView like I did in two other places in my project.

To start, I know I have a valid Bitmap because the debugger shows it and it gets displayed in two other ImageViews. Nonetheless, here is my code to get the Bitmap.

```
    public static Bitmap getThumbnail(AudioUri audioURI, Context context){
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            try {
                bitmap = context.getContentResolver().loadThumbnail(
                        audioURI.getUri(), new Size(128, 128), null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            try {
                mmr.setDataSource(context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(
                        audioURI.getUri(), "r").getFileDescriptor());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            if (mmr.getEmbeddedPicture() != null) {
                inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
            }
            mmr.release();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

I am not sure the else part works because I have not yet tested it.

Here is my successful attempt at loading a Bitmap into an ImageView the first time.

The xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_song_art"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="14"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/music_note_black_48dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Here is where I load the BitMap

```
    private void updateSongArt() {
        ImageView imageViewSongArt = findViewById(R.id.image_view_song_art);
        if (imageViewSongArt != null && serviceMain != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap =
                    AudioUri.getThumbnail(serviceMain.getCurrentSong(), getApplicationContext());
            if (bitmap == null) {
                imageViewSongArt.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.music_note_black_48dp, null));
                imageViewSongArt.setBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                imageViewSongArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                imageViewSongArt.setBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOnPrimary));
            }
        }
    }
```

<strike>I am assuming I got lucky here because I did not do any dynamic resizing. This leads me to believe my dynamic resizing is wrong.</strike> 
I added dynamic resizing to the code above and the Bitmap is correctly displayed.

```
    private void updateSongArt() {
        ImageView imageViewSongArt = findViewById(R.id.image_view_song_art);
        if (imageViewSongArt != null && serviceMain != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap =
                    AudioUri.getThumbnail(serviceMain.getCurrentSong(), getApplicationContext());
            if (bitmap == null) {
                imageViewSongArt.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.music_note_black_48dp, null));
                imageViewSongArt.setBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                    int songArtHeight = imageViewSongArt.getMeasuredHeight();
                    if (songArtHeight < 1) {
                        songArtHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                    }
                int songArtWidth = imageViewSongArt.getMeasuredWidth();
                if (songArtWidth < 1) {
                    songArtWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                }
                if(songArtWidth > songArtHeight){
                    songArtWidth = songArtHeight;
                } else{
                    songArtHeight = songArtWidth;
                }
                Bitmap bitmap2 = FragmentPaneSong.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, songArtWidth, songArtHeight);
                if(bitmap2 != null) {
                    imageViewSongArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
                } else {
                    imageViewSongArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                imageViewSongArt.setBackgroundColor(
                        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOnPrimary));
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the failing code

The xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSongPaneSongArt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/music_note_black_48dp" />
```

Here I get the width and height and resize and set the Bitmap to the ImageView.

```
 private void updateSongPaneArt() {
        int songArtHeight = getSongArtHeight();
        int songArtWidth = getSongArtWidth();
        setImageViewSongPaneArt(songArtWidth, songArtHeight);
    }

    private int getSongArtHeight() {
        ImageView imageViewSongPaneSongArt = findViewById(R.id.imageViewSongPaneSongArt);
        if (imageViewSongPaneSongArt != null && serviceMain != null) {
            int songArtHeight = imageViewSongPaneSongArt.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (songArtHeight > 0) {
                serviceMain.setSongPaneArtHeight(songArtHeight);
            } else {
                songArtHeight = serviceMain.getSongPaneArtHeight();
            }
            return songArtHeight;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int getSongArtWidth() {
        ImageView imageViewSongPaneSongArt = findViewById(R.id.imageViewSongPaneSongArt);
        if (imageViewSongPaneSongArt != null && serviceMain != null) {
            int songArtWidth = imageViewSongPaneSongArt.getMeasuredWidth();
            if (songArtWidth > 0) {
                serviceMain.setSongPaneArtWidth(songArtWidth);
            } else {
                songArtWidth = serviceMain.getSongPaneArtWidth();
            }
            return songArtWidth;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void setImageViewSongPaneArt(int songArtWidth, int songArtHeight) {
        ImageView imageViewSongPaneSongArt = findViewById(R.id.imageViewSongPaneSongArt);
        if (imageViewSongPaneSongArt != null && serviceMain != null) {
            Bitmap bitmapSongArt = AudioUri.getThumbnail(
                    serviceMain.getCurrentSong(), getApplicationContext());
            if (bitmapSongArt != null) {
                Bitmap bitmapSongArtResized = FragmentPaneSong.getResizedBitmap(
                        bitmapSongArt, songArtWidth, songArtHeight);
                imageViewSongPaneSongArt.setImageDrawable(null);
                imageViewSongPaneSongArt.setImageBitmap(bitmapSongArtResized);
                imageViewSongPaneSongArt.invalidate();
            } else {
                Bitmap defaultBitmap = getDefaultBitmap(songArtWidth, songArtHeight);
                if (defaultBitmap != null) {
                    imageViewSongPaneSongArt.setImageBitmap(defaultBitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(
                bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    }
```

I have tried removing the margins from the dimensions and that does not work. The Bitmap that is generated by the getResizedBitmap() method has the correct size; the debugger verifies it. It matches the width `int songArtWidth = imageViewSongPaneSongArt.getMeasuredWidth();` which I verified gets returned as the width. I am not sure what is going on.

I can set the Bitmap without resizing and it expands to the large size, but it uses the drawable as the image still. Even after `imageViewSongPaneSongArt.setImageDrawable(null);`. These are the only spots in my code where the ImageView is mutated and the debugger shows that `imageViewSongPaneSongArt.setImageBitmap(defaultBitmap);` IS NOT called.

I have also tried to invalidate the ImageView with no success.

What is going on?

Comment: Try giving the _ImageView_ a definite size for a test to see if the bitmap displays. You don't need `imageViewSongPaneSongArt.setImageDrawable(null)`. It is unclear exactly what does get displayed if anything. Does the _ImageView_ have any size at all when displayed. An MCVE would be helpful for anyone looking to answer this question.

Comment: Yea, the ImageView has a size. The drawable in the xml is what gets displayed. The ImageView takes on the size of the Bitmap even though the Bitmap isn't getting displayed.

Comment: What is `getDefaultBitmap()`?

Comment: Allow me to say that this is complexity at its best. To fetch an album art (in my case a thumbnail of the album art ), I use a simple Uri method then set the uri to the image view directly.

Comment: Example? I have tried many things I have found on StackOverflow, because the devs at Google decided to only document how to support new apis. This is the only thing that has worked with MediaStore Uris.